# Xcode Build script for conditional SPM dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, dependency-management, swift-package-manager

I'm migrating a project from Cocoapods to SPM, but I'm stuck on an issue where we only need to use certain dependencies in conditional cases.

Cocoapods has an easy solution for this:

```
if ENV['enabled'].to_i == 1
 pod 'Google'
end
```

As far as I know, conditional dependencies are only partially supported in SPM and it isn't enough for my problem:
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0273-swiftpm-conditional-target-dependencies.md

I was thinking about creating a build phase script to manually include the framework as a target member based on the environmental variable condition.

Looking for a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

"Package.swift" is a regular swift file and you can write any code for your logic and conditions inside. For instance, you can check environment variables with `ProcessInfo` and assemble needed arrays of dependencies:

```swift
import PackageDescription
import Foundation

let useRealm = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["realm"] == "1"

let packageDependencies: [Package.Dependency] = useRealm
    ? [.package(url: "https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git", from: "10.15.1")]
    : []

let targetDependencies: [Target.Dependency] = useRealm
    ? [.product(name: "Realm", package: "realm-cocoa")]
    : []

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v12),
        .macOS(.v10_14)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyPackage", targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: packageDependencies,
    targets: [
        .target(name: "MyPackage", dependencies: targetDependencies),
        .testTarget(name: "MyPackageTests", dependencies: ["MyPackage"]),
    ]
)
```

Now you can build your package with no dependencies:

```
$ xcrun --sdk macosx swift build
Building for debugging...
[2/2] Emitting module MyPackage
Build complete! (0.77s)
```

And with the Realm dependency by setting `realm=1` in the environment variables:

```
$ export realm=1
$ xcrun --sdk macosx swift build
Fetching https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git from cache
Fetched https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git (2.12s)
Computing version for https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git
Computed https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git at 10.32.0 (0.02s)
Fetching https://github.com/realm/realm-core from cache
Fetched https://github.com/realm/realm-core (1.37s)
Computing version for https://github.com/realm/realm-core
Computed https://github.com/realm/realm-core at 12.9.0 (0.02s)
Creating working copy for https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git
Working copy of https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git resolved at 10.32.0
Creating working copy for https://github.com/realm/realm-core
Working copy of https://github.com/realm/realm-core resolved at 12.9.0
Building for debugging...
[63/63] Compiling MyPackage MyPackage.swift
Build complete! (41.64s)
```

Comment: Nice work, iUrii! But to use this skill we have to build with the command line, right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer iUrii, unfortunately I have no package.swift file since I'm using it for an XCode project and not a swift package.

Comment: I wonder the same. Started a bounty. This answer does not seem to apply for Xcode projects.

Comment: @PeterLendvay You can create a local swift package to wrapper the "Google" package, and then include this local package into Xcode, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/organizing-your-code-with-local-packages

Comment: @JIEWANG The approach with local swift package is not applicable to manage package dependencies with environment variables etc. because XCode runs Package.swift code (Resolving package graph)  in the separate process before building and doesn't share any Swift Active Compilation Flags or environment variables from a project settings.